# Using F1 Score with TFBertForSequenceClassification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I am training a Bert model for a downstream task and trying to asses the model using F1 score but I run into a shape mismatch issue

```
from transformers import TFBertForSequenceClassification
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa 

nlabels = 26

tfa_f1_score = tfa.metrics.FBetaScore(num_classes=nlabels,average="macro",threshold=0.6,name= 'f1_score')
# recommended learning rate for Adam 5e-5, 3e-5, 2e-5
learning_rate = 5e-5

# we will do just 1 epoch for illustration, though multiple epochs might be better as long as we will not overfit the model
number_of_epochs = 10


# model initialization
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=nlabels,
                                                      output_attentions=False,
                                                      output_hidden_states=False)

# optimizer Adam
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=1e-08)

# we do not have one-hot vectors, we can use sparce categorical cross entropy and accuracy
loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[tfa_f1_score])

bert_history = model.fit(ds_tr_encoded, epochs=number_of_epochs)
```

This results in the following error

> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 26 and
>
> 1. Shapes are [26] and [1]. for '{{node AssignAddVariableOp_5}} = AssignAddVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT](AssignAddVariableOp_5/resource,
>    Sum_5)' with input shapes: [], [1].

How do i resolve this?

Complete error

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-41e29580dec4> in <module>
----> 1 bert_history = model.fit(ds_tr_encoded, epochs=number_of_epochs)

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883   @property
    884   def _run_functions_eagerly(self):
--> 885     return RUN_FUNCTIONS_EAGERLY
    886 
    887   @traceback_utils.filter_traceback

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931 
    932     return result
--> 933 
    934   def _call(self, *args, **kwds):
    935     """Calls the graph function."""

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    758             arglen:required_arg_len]
    759         raise TypeError(
--> 760             f"The decorated function {self._name} has {required_arg_len} "
    761             f"required argument(s), but tf.function was only passed an "
    762             f"input_signature of length {arglen}. This covers {arglen} "

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3064     Args:
   3065       *args: inputs to specialize on. Can be concrete values (e.g. 1)
-> 3066          or `tf.Tensor` or `tf.TensorSpec`.
   3067       **kwargs: keyword inputs to specialize on. Concrete values (e.g. 1)
   3068          or `tf.Tensor` or `tf.TensorSpec`.

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3461   of Tensor shapes and dtypes and Python values, it constructs a graph by
   3462   tracing the execution of `f(*args, **kwargs)`; this graph is bound to an
-> 3463   input signature inferred from `(*args, **kwargs)` and cached for future reuse.
   3464 
   3465   NumPy arrays passed as inputs to `F` are converted to `tf.Tensor` objects

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3306   Args:
   3307     func: the `Function` instance that generated by a @defun
-> 3308     *args: input arguments for the Python function.
   3309     **kwargs: input keyword arguments for the Python function.
   3310 

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)
   1005     arg_names: Optional list of argument names, used to give input placeholders
   1006       recognizable names.
-> 1007     op_return_value: Optional. A Tensor. If set and `python_func` returns
   1008       Operations, those return values will be replaced with this value. If not
   1009       set, returning an Operation triggers an error.

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    666       # If an outer variable creator calls the variable constructor manually,
    667       # for example creating a MirroredVariable, then they won't call our
--> 668       # creator. This means we won't be able to trace the initialization graph,
    669       # and so variable initializers can't depend on function arguments. This is
    670       # better than the alternative, tracing the initialization graph but giving

~/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992       and dtypes of the arguments. When a signature is provided, `args` and
    993       `kwargs` are ignored, and `python_func` is traced with Tensors conforming
--> 994       to `signature`. If `None`, the shapes and dtypes are inferred from the
    995       inputs.
    996     func_graph: Optional. An instance of FuncGraph. If provided, we will use

ValueError: in user code:

    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_addons/metrics/f_scores.py:167 update_state  *
        self.weights_intermediate.assign_add(_weighted_sum(y_true, sample_weight))
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/mixed_precision/autocast_variable.py:249 assign_add  **
        use_locking, name, read_value)
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/mixed_precision/autocast_variable.py:217 _apply_assign_update
        assign_op = update_fn(value, use_locking, name, False)
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:858 assign_add
        read_value: A `bool`. Whether to read and return the new value of the
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_resource_variable_ops.py:57 assign_add_variable_op
        "AssignAddVariableOp", resource=resource, value=value, name=name)
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:750 _apply_op_helper
        if op_callbacks.should_invoke_op_callbacks():
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:601 _create_op_internal
        name=None,
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3569 _create_op_internal
        
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:2042 __init__
        control_inputs=None,
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1883 _create_c_op
        RuntimeError: If a registered conversion function returns an invalid

    ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 26 and 1. Shapes are [26] and [1]. for '{{node AssignAddVariableOp_5}} = AssignAddVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT](AssignAddVariableOp_5/resource, Sum_5)' with input shapes: [], [1].
```

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: the last line, on fitting. Added the trace

Comment: it can be that your data is not in the right format. If you have only the correct label in your data given to the model it wont work. That's why it complains that there is a tensor with one dimension. For each sample, the target should be a vector of (num_labels,) where all labels are binarised. For instance if a sample has labels 2,3, your target will be [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...., 0]

Comment: If it is not a multi-label but multi-class classification, I think what I said still applies. You need a vector where every dimension is 0 except for the correct class, ffor which it is 1